# Multiple alignment points in equations and no curly brackets for correcting spacing

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, amsmath

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{5}
  &\text{Honning:}\qquad
  &&\frac{\SI{16710}{\g}}{\SI{33075}{\g}} \cdot \SI{360}{\degree}
  &&= {\mkern -6mu}\left(\frac{\num{16710} \cdot 360}{\num{33075}}\right){\mkern -6mu}\,\si{\degree}
  &&\approx{} &\SI{182}{\degree}&;\\
  &\text{Pollen:}
  &&\frac{\SI{10155}{\g}}{\SI{33075}{\g}} \cdot \SI{360}{\degree}
  &&= {\mkern -6mu}\left(\frac{\num{10155} \cdot 360}{\num{33075}}\right){\mkern -6mu}\,\si{\degree}
  &&\approx{} &\SI{111}{\degree}&;\\
  &\text{Vand:}
  &&\frac{\SI{6210}{\g}}{\SI{33075}{\g}} \cdot \SI{360}{\degree}
  &&= {\mkern -6mu}\left(\frac{6210 \cdot 360}{\num{33075}}\right){\mkern -6mu}\,\si{\degree}
  &&\approx{} &\SI{68}{\degree}&.
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Is it possible to get the same alignment and spacing without putting `{}` after `\approx`?

**Update**

After simplifying [Werner's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160134/15874) even further, I've come up with the following solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calculate \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand*\pieSlice[1]{%
  \dfrac{\SI{#1}{\g}}{\SI{\total}{\g}} \cdot \SI{360}{\degree}
  & {\mkern -3mu}\biggl(\dfrac{\num{#1} \cdot 360}{\num{\total}}\biggr){\mkern -3mu} \si{\degree}
  & \calculate{round(#1*360/\total)} \si{\degree}
  &
}
\newcommand*\total{\calculate{\honning+\pollen+\vand}}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\def\honning{16710}
\def\pollen{10155}
\def\vand{6210}
 \renewcommand*\arraystretch{2.2}
  \begin{array}{l@{\qquad} l@{{}={}} l@{{}\approx{}} r@{} l}
    \text{Honning:} & \pieSlice{\honning}; \\
    \text{Pollen:}  & \pieSlice{\pollen}; \\
    \text{Vand:}    & \pieSlice{\vand}.
  \end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Define `\newcommand{\Approx}{{}\approx{}}` and then use `\Approx` instead of `\approx`. :-)

Comment: @PeterGrill That is cheating `:)` and them I'm still using `{}`.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with using `{}`? What if the answer is no?

Comment: @Werner There's nothing wrong with it at all. I was just hoping that it would be possible in order to simplify the code as much as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the construction is consistent and doesn't require numbering, you can define a macro to handle each row, constructing an array as needed:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\calculation}[2]{% \calculation{<num>}{<denom>}
  \dfrac{\SI{#1}{\g}}{\SI{#2}{\g}} \cdot \SI{360}{\degree}
  & \biggl( \dfrac{\num{#1} \cdot 360}{\num{#2}} \biggr) \si{\degree}
  & \fp_eval:n {round(#1 * 360 / #2)} \si{\degree}
  &
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.1}
  \begin{array}{l@{\qquad}l@{{}={}}l@{{}\approx{}}r@{}l}
    \text{Honning:} & \calculation{16710}{33075}; \\
    \text{Pollen:}  & \calculation{10155}{33075}; \\
    \text{Vand:}    & \calculation{6210}{33075}.
  \end{array}
\]


\end{document}
```

Apart from the column specification (which handles the spacing; and could be modified), the code is probably better to read. Of course, it could be simplified even further.

Comment: I really like this solution! You say it can be simplified even further; can I make you do that? `:)`

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: One simplification I've added is to calculate `<answer>` using `l3fp` (which is loaded indirectly by [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx)). I've used `round`.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `&` following the `\approx`, here are two ways you can achieve the desired result:

1. Add a `\phantom{1}` for the last case to right align it.
2. Define a custom `MySI` which uses `\makebox` to make sure that the text is right aligned within the appropriate width.

### Code: `\phantom`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{5}
  &\text{Honning:}\qquad
  &&\frac{\SI{16710}{\g}}{\SI{33075}{\g}} \cdot \SI{360}{\degree}
  &&= {\mkern -6mu}\left(\frac{\num{16710} \cdot 360}{\num{33075}}\right){\mkern -6mu}\,\si{\degree}
  &&\approx \SI{182}{\degree}&;\\
  &\text{Pollen:}
  &&\frac{\SI{10155}{\g}}{\SI{33075}{\g}} \cdot \SI{360}{\degree}
  &&= {\mkern -6mu}\left(\frac{\num{10155} \cdot 360}{\num{33075}}\right){\mkern -6mu}\,\si{\degree}
  &&\approx \SI{111}{\degree}&;\\
  &\text{Vand:}
  &&\frac{\SI{6210}{\g}}{\SI{33075}{\g}} \cdot \SI{360}{\degree}
  &&= {\mkern -6mu}\left(\frac{6210 \cdot 360}{\num{33075}}\right){\mkern -6mu}\,\si{\degree}
  &&\approx \phantom{1}\SI{68}{\degree}&.
\end{alignat*}
```

### Code: `\MySI`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand*{\MySI}[2]{\makebox[\widthof{\SI{999}{#2}}][r]{\SI{#1}{#2}}}%

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{5}
  &\text{Honning:}\qquad
  &&\frac{\SI{16710}{\g}}{\SI{33075}{\g}} \cdot \SI{360}{\degree}
  &&= {\mkern -6mu}\left(\frac{\num{16710} \cdot 360}{\num{33075}}\right){\mkern -6mu}\,\si{\degree}
  &&\approx \MySI{182}{\degree};\\
  &\text{Pollen:}
  &&\frac{\SI{10155}{\g}}{\SI{33075}{\g}} \cdot \SI{360}{\degree}
  &&= {\mkern -6mu}\left(\frac{\num{10155} \cdot 360}{\num{33075}}\right){\mkern -6mu}\,\si{\degree}
  &&\approx \MySI{111}{\degree};\\
  &\text{Vand:}
  &&\frac{\SI{6210}{\g}}{\SI{33075}{\g}} \cdot \SI{360}{\degree}
  &&= {\mkern -6mu}\left(\frac{6210 \cdot 360}{\num{33075}}\right){\mkern -6mu}\,\si{\degree}
  &&\approx \MySI{68}{\degree}.
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: My 'problem' with this is (a) that one should use 2n-1 `&`'s for n `&` (I think) and (b) the `\phantom{1}` 'gets rit of' the simplicity, I think.

Comment: Much better using `{}`, I think...

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: Ok, how about the revised solution where you don't need to manually add a `\phantom{1}` spacing?

Comment: A nice try but I'm really fond of this. If no one comes up with a solution involving just the initial code without the curly braces, I'll accept your answer later today.

Answer (score 1):

This answer replaces the `\alignat` with a `\alignShortstack` from the just released `tabstackengine` package (may or may not have propagated to a CTAN mirror near you).

The good news:  1) the `approx` does not need a `{}`; and 2) the result looks the same

The bad news: 1) it runs very slow (I am not sure why); and 2) the lone `\qquad` needs a `{}` (I am not sure why).

EDITED because I can use it in `\centering` situations (by changing the EOL character from `\\` to, for example, `\#`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\makeatletter
\newcommand\TABstackDisplay{\renewcommand\TAB@delim[1]{\displaystyle##1}}
\makeatother
\TABstackDisplay
\setstackaligngap{0ex}
\setstackgap{S}{4pt}
\setstackEOL{\#}
\begin{document}
{\centering
\alignShortstack{
  &\text{Honning:}\qquad{}
  &&\frac{\SI{16710}{\g}}{\SI{33075}{\g}} \cdot \SI{360}{\degree}
  &&= {\mkern -6mu}\left(\frac{\num{16710} \cdot 360}{\num{33075}}\right){\mkern -6mu}\,\si{\degree}
  &&\approx &\SI{182}{\degree}&;\#
  &\text{Pollen:}
  &&\frac{\SI{10155}{\g}}{\SI{33075}{\g}} \cdot \SI{360}{\degree}
  &&= {\mkern -6mu}\left(\frac{\num{10155} \cdot 360}{\num{33075}}\right){\mkern -6mu}\,\si{\degree}
  &&\approx &\SI{111}{\degree}&;\#
  &\text{Vand:}
  &&\frac{\SI{6210}{\g}}{\SI{33075}{\g}} \cdot \SI{360}{\degree}
  &&= {\mkern -6mu}\left(\frac{6210 \cdot 360}{\num{33075}}\right){\mkern -6mu}\,\si{\degree}
  &&\approx &\SI{68}{\degree}&.
}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution with only 3 alignment points and `one` pair of braces (as a spacing argument of the alignat* environment – first line):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
 &   \text{Honning:}\qquad
 &\frac{\SI{16710}{\g}}{\SI{33075}{\g}}  · \SI{360}{\degree}
 &= {\mkern -6mu}\left(\frac{\num{16710}  · 360}{\num{33075}}\right){\mkern -6mu}\,\si{\degree}
 &{}&\approx {} \SI{182}{\degree};\\
 &  \text{Pollen:}
 &\frac{\SI{10155}{\g}}{\SI{33075}{\g}}  · \SI{360}{\degree}
 &= {\mkern -6mu}\left(\frac{\num{10155}  · 360}{\num{33075}}\right){\mkern -6mu}\,\si{\degree}
 & & \approx{} \SI{111}{\degree};\\
 &  \text{Vand:}
 & \frac{\SI{6210}{\g}}{\SI{33075}{\g}}  · \SI{360}{\degree}
 &= {\mkern -6mu}\left(\frac{6210  · 360}{\num{33075}}\right){\mkern -6mu}\,\si{\degree}
 &&\approx{} \SI{68}{\degree} .
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Resulting in:

[image]

If you prefer the last series of units to be right aligned, just add a `\hphantom{0}` in front of  `\SIunit{68}`:

[image]

Comment: This is all good but I need five alignment points. `:)` The output is also not as I would like.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: your picture describing your problem doesn't require 5 points, but only 3. I suppose you have other requirements; could you explain?

Comment: Alignment points: At the first text, at the first numbers, at the `=`, at the `\approx` and at the `\degree`.

Comment: I still don't understand: for me, I produced the same picture as yours, with only 3 points of alignment points and a \hphantom. The first numbers will be aligned on the right side by definition, and they will be on their left side because the have the same size. The final degrees will be aligned because of the \hphantom. So what did I miss?

Comment: I don't know how to say it differently. Never mind; I appreciate your try. `:)`