# Separate LaTeX 3 code from 'normal' \newcommand

Tags: latex3, code

Consider the example from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160127/multiple-alignment-points-in-equations-and-no-curly-brackets-for-correcting-spac):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand*\calculation[1]{%
  \dfrac{\SI{#1}{\g}}{\SI{\total}{\g}} \cdot \SI{360}{\degree}
  & \biggl(\dfrac{\num{#1} \cdot 360}{\num{\total}}\biggr) \si{\degree}
  & \fp_eval:n {round(#1*360/\total)} \si{\degree}
  &
}
\cs_new_eq:NN \calculate \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand*\total{\calculate{\honning+\pollen+\vand}}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\def\honning{16710}
\def\pollen{10155}
\def\vand{6210}
 \renewcommand*\arraystretch{2.2}
  \begin{array}{l@{\qquad} l@{{}={}} l@{{}\approx{}} r@{} l}
    \text{Honning:} & \calculation{\honning}; \\
    \text{Pollen:}  & \calculation{\pollen}; \\
    \text{Vand:}    & \calculation{\vand}.
  \end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to put the definition of `\calculation` outside `\ExplSyntaxOn`/`\ExplSyntaxOff`? I would like to have something like

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calculate \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand*\total{\calculate{\honning+\pollen+\vand}}
\newcommand*\calculation[1]{%
  \dfrac{\SI{#1}{\g}}{\SI{\total}{\g}} \cdot \SI{360}{\degree}
  & \biggl(\dfrac{\num{#1} \cdot 360}{\num{\total}}\biggr) \si{\degree}
  & \fp_eval:n {round(#1*360/\total)} \si{\degree}
  &
}
```

This makes the code a bit easier to navigate through, I think.

If I try the latter, I get the following error.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\calculation ...l }}\biggr ) \si {\degree } & \fp 
                                                  _eval:n {round(#1*360/\tot...
l.26     \text{Honning:} & \calculation{\honning}
                                                 ; \\
```

P.S. Notice that I know (almost) nothing about L3, so please no explanation that are "too fancy". `:)`

**Update**

As Joseph hinted in his last comment below, the only problem was that I wasn't thinking.

Comment: Of course it is: did your try your second version?

Comment: @JosephWright: (Without trying it) The definition of `\calculation` contains `\fp_eval:n` which is only valid inside the L3 syntax. Isn’t it …?

Comment: @JosephWright See updated question.

Comment: @Tobi That seems to be the case but as I say, I know nothing of L3 (except that it's awesome to use its features).

Comment: I'm confused: if you set `\calculate` equal to `\fp_eval:n` why are you then using the latter rather than just `\calcualate` inside `\calculation`?

Comment: @JosephWright Because I'm not thinking. `:(` A 'new' syntax is somewhat confusing but you are of course alsolutely right; it works just fine. (Should I delete my question?)

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: Beside the solution of setting “normal” macro equal to L3 ones, why do you want to separate code in this way? I think grouping code parts by topic and not by syntax makes more sense to me. Furthermore I think using the `\cs_set_eq` way is no good idea, because other that read your code might oversee the “letting” and thus your code is hard to read than it could be. Is there a reason that you don’t use `\NewDocumentCommand` it’s much more powerful than `\newcommand`. Plus: in L3 syntax you must not care about spurious spaces ;-)

Comment: @Tobi I'm going to repeat myself: I'm not familiar with L3 at all, but I should probably follow your advices. (Regarding the code separation, I find it easier to read when all the `\newcommand`s are collected in one place.)

Comment: @JosephWright Sounds like an answer (or at least a reason to close(?)) :-)